# Java call method in Main class

Tags: java, oop, class

Let's say I have `Main` class, and it has an instance of class `A`.

How can I call a method in `Main` class within class `A` ?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's a static method, call it as such. If it's not a static method then [the method in] `A` needs an instance of `Main` [to invoke the method upon], no? However, I'd suggest avoiding "cycles" like this in most cases..

Comment: Why dont you use get method on class A object get values into main class, manipulate with local methods and send the result value back into class A object with set method

Comment: Your best bet is to take what is in `Main` and put it into a `B` class. Then have `A` reference `B`, and have `Main` just do things like `A a = new A();` and `a.doSomething();`.

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Composition`...**Where a class has a Reference of other class...**

`Composition` is **preferred over** `Inheritance` when we need **one or few functionalities But Not all the functionalities of a class.**

**Eg:**

```
public class A{

 Main m = new M();  // m is a Object Reference Variable of type Main in class A
 m.go();           // go() is a method in class Main

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an instance method, then you need an instance of M inside A to call M's method inside A. If it is a static method, you can just call it directly. But you're holding circular references so beware.

Answer (score 0):

Main.methodName() for a static method.

Though it sounds to me like what you're trying to do may be bad practice. Your Main method or class should simply be an entry point

Answer (score 0):

To call a method in Main class from calss A you need an instance of Main class within the class A(considering them in same package) if both the calsses have no relation like inheritance.if static then you may call Main.methodName();

Answer (score 0):

If the method is a static method (i.e. was declared with "public static ReturnType methodName()") then in the A class, you need to call Main.methodName().

However, if the method is an instance method (declared as "public ReturnType methodName()") then you need to somehow pass an instance of Main into the instance of A (perhaps through the constructor, or a setter method). Inside the A class, you could then call instanceOfMain.methodName().

However (as some people have already mentioned) this is probably not the best way to handle things. The Main class should simply be where the program starts; it is not where you should be doing any real program logic.